# why do you need to put branch name in git pull remote <branch> if the updated branch is where you are?

Tags: git-pull

when I do a git "pull origin master" from a branch the branch is updated NOT the master. In order to update the master I need to do a "git checkout master" and then call "git pull origin master". Why is "master" needed in the command if the updates take place to the current branch and not necessarily the master.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is specifying the branch on the remote end that you want to merge with your current branch. So `git pull origin master` literally means: consult the repository at the URL defined by the `origin` remote, check it's `master` branch, download whatever I need to have a copy of that branch in my repo (which will be saved as a branch called `origin/master`), and merge that branch into whatever branch I happen to be on at the moment.